# How do I paste time into a time data validation cell without error?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

For most data validation cells with drop down lists, I find that if I paste one of the values in the list exactly, there's no error.

However, with my drop down list of time values (Ex. "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", etc.), if I paste "5:00 PM" into the cell, I get an error. Is there a way to paste time values without an error? Does it have something to do with the annoying invisible seconds column (as it appears in the formula bar, "5:00:00 PM")?

[Picture of error showing after pasting a time that's in the list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlxx6.png)

[Picture of my list of times. Note the seconds place in the formula bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLJFh.png)

Comment: Check the cell format.

Comment: @Lee cell format is "Time". I've also tried "Custom" (h:mm AM/PM).